# Why can Android Keystore not load public key

Tags: android-keystore

Why does AndroidKeystore can not load public key certificate?

I am trying to load public key from Android Keystore. But on some devices the public key can not be loaded with the following exception.
Can someone pls explain me why this situation happens?

The error happes mainly on Samsung, Lenovo, Huawei and LG devices with OS version 4+, 5+, 6+ and 7+.

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Failed to obtain X.509 form of public key
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePublicKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:223)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyPairFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:252)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePrivateKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:263)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetKey(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:93)
   at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:372)
   at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:645)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1037)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6322)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:222)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1862)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: OK
   at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:913)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePublicKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:223)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyPairFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:252)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePrivateKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:263)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetKey(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:93)
   at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:372)
   at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:645)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1037)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6322)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:222)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1862)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```